# How to get value the closest element to the current position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color: aqua">
        <td>Malzeme No</td>
        <td>Malzeme Adı</td>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMalzemeList" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="malzlist">
                <td><%#Eval("MATNR") %></td>
                <td><%#Eval("MAKTX") %></td> // I want this value
                <td><a href="#" id="btnSec" onclick="sendValue(this)">Seç</a></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

My JavaScript function like this,

```
function sendValue(objs)
{
    var MalzName = objs.parent().parent().children().next().text();
    alert(MalzName);
    window.opener.HandlePopupResult(MalzName);
    window.close();
}
```

but, it is given error undefined is a not function.Can you help me please?

Comment: try out for siblings in jquery . [http://api.jquery.com/siblings/]. this would help you find the elements with in same level.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
var MalzName = objs.parent().parent().children().next().text();
```

to:

```
var MalzName = $(objs).parent().prev().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`objs` is a DOM Element, not a jQuery wrapper.  The first line of your function should convert it:

```
objs = $(objs);
```

Then you have a shot at it working.  Not commenting on the other aspects of the function at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to avoid inline JS and use the following:

HTML:

```
<td><a href="#" id="btnSec">Seç</a></td>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
   $('#btnSec').on('click',function() {
       var MalzName = $(this).parent().prev().text();
       alert(MalzName);
       window.opener.HandlePopupResult(MalzName);
       window.close();
    });
});
```

OR:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSec').on('click', sendValue);
});

function sendValue()
{
    var MalzName = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    alert(MalzName);
    window.opener.HandlePopupResult(MalzName);
    window.close();
}
```